# Zend Framework 2 - Queries

Tags: zend-framework2

i am working on ZF2. I would like to print the queries. How can i do in model files?

I am doing the form validation with db records - for already exist condition.

But, it would not work. So, i like to trouble-shoot the queries.

Comment: Please look at some questions other people ask on StackOverflow. You have asked a lot of questions lately about Zend Framework 2, but all questions are very short, not specific and show not much of what you have tried already. Also, all answers given to your questions are never accepted as an answer. Please revise your question, show a minimal working example or link to resources you have already looked into.

Comment: Thanks, but i never expect such an activity from you.

Comment: i will change. i need your suggestions in future.

Comment: But, i would not get solutions from your replies. Not only for this question alone. For Most of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply do:

```
echo $this->getSql();
```

Although this isn't a recommended way, but it works in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

If your using TableGateway for executing queries then try the below piece of code.

After constructing the whole $select object -

```
$select = new Select(database_table_name);
$select->join(...);
$select->where(...);
...
....
$select->order(...);

/*Required lines of code to print the whole query*/
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($this->tableGateway->adapter);
echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
exit();   //(optional)
```